# Angular Material 17 - How to get primary color from theme in Style.scss

Tags: angular, sass, angular-material, angular-upgrade, angular17

I have just upgraded angular app from 16 to 17. Application has custom theme as below.

custTheme.scss

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;

@include mat.core();

$pp: mat.define-palette(mat.$indigo-palette);
$primary: mat.get-color-from-palette($pp);
$ap: mat.define-palette(mat.$pink-palette);
$accent: mat.get-color-from-palette($ap);
$wp: mat.define-palette(mat.$red-palette);
$warn: mat.get-color-from-palette($wp);

$theme: mat.define-light-theme((
 color: (
   primary: $pp,
   accent: $ap,
   warn: $wp,
 ),
 typography: mat.define-typography-config(),
));

@include mat.all-component-themes($theme);
```

this seem to be working fine except when I try to get primary color in Style.scss, it doesn't work

style.scss

```
import '/custTheme';
background-color: mat-color($primary, darker);
```

It doesn't seem to recognise mat-color function. what I get in browser is

```
color: mat-color(#616161, darker);
```

Can someone please explain what's happening here?

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We need to import the theme and angular material root import, then we can use `mat.get-color-from-palette` and input the palette and the shade required and it will work!

```
@use '@angular/material' as mat;
@import './theme.scss';

body {
  font-family: Roboto, 'Helvetica Neue', sans-serif;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 30px;
  background-color: mat.get-color-from-palette($pp, 'darker') !important;
  // background-color: $primary !important;
}

html,
body {
  height: 100%;
}
```

[<kbd>**`Stackblitz Demo`**</kbd>](https://stackblitz.com/edit/hewy3q?file=src%2Fstyles.scss,src%2Ftheme.scss)

Comment: I have a followup question: https://stackoverflow.com/q/78033291/325868